# Performance issues with the existing coding approach using global :: keyword

Tags: c#, .net

I have been asked to refactor a particular module in my application and also to tweak some

performance related issues (if any).

Coming to the module,there are certain portions where it needs some strings to be

displayed. Also the strings are supplied by a Language assembly(.dll) which is

referred in my project, which basically returns a string from an XML file containing

strings if you pass a keyword.

For ex:

**Language.GetStringFromID("TXT_WARNING");** would return something like **Warning !!**

The original developer has generously used

**global :: Language.GetInstance().GetStringFromID("KEYWORD")** whenever to fetch a string

**Question 1,**
Is this a good approach ??

I had the second thoughts about this approach, i ran a performance profiler and i see that

everytime when string is requested, it nearly takes **500ms** to return the string for the

queried keyword.

Before i conclude that this is indeed the culprit, i need some thoughts from .NET Experts

in StackOverflow

**Question 2**

Is there any performance hit if we use **global ::**  in general ??

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It only should be used to eliminate namespace conflicts.
2. No performance hit with using `global::`. It's handled by the compiler. Theres nothing about namespaces at runtime.

The performance hit is inside `Language.GetStringFromID`

Comment: Thanks.  But do you agree this is a bad practice using Language.GetInstance().GetStringFromID everytime ??

Comment: It depends on the implementation of it. I would look to see if you could start using resources using Resx files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68135h5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `global` keyword has no implication on performance *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of global:: is always what is used at the IL level, there is no concept of using a namespace there. In other words it is irrelevant for runtime performance.